# How to trigger drag event from a draggable child

Tags: flutter, draggable

I have a widget wrapped with `LongPressDraggable` widget with a delay of 100ms.
The child widget is card and the whole child should be dragged but I want to use a drag handle to trigger the drag.
Is it possible to trigger the drag event only from the child drag handle?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you find any solutions?